# Codeigniter how to fetch session data in view

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I have set session, i want send data login autho controller to profile controller using ajax and jquery

```
    public function login_autho() {
            $this->load->library('session');
            $data = array(
                'uname' => $this->input->post('uname'),
                'upassword' => $this->input->post('upassword')
            );
            //fetch database usename and password
            $result = $this->login_model->login_user($data);

            //user name put in the session
            $data_session_set = array('logged' => 1, 'uname' => $this->input->post('uname'));
            $data = $this->session->set_userdata($data_session_set);

            print_r($result);
        }

        public function profile() {
            $this->load->view('header');
            //How to send user name from here  to success view page  and fetch  all data
            $this->load->view('user/success');

        }
```

This is my ajax script in the login form to check user name and pass then login

```
   <script>
    $('#login_form').submit(function (e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        var uname = $('#uname').val();
        var upassword = $('#upassword').val();
        if (uname == "" || upassword == "")
        {
            $('#error').show().html('All Fields are required');
        } else {
            $('#error').html("").hide();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?= base_url(); ?>User_controller/login_autho/",
                data: {uname: uname, upassword: upassword},
                success: function (data) {
                    //if session is set then redirect to User_controller/profile but session can send data
                    if (data == '1')
                    {
                        window.location.replace("<?= base_url(); ?>User_controller/profile");

                    } else
                    {
                        alert('invalid');
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Is your AJAX load the view after logged in ??

Comment: yes it is loading in profile controller success .php

Comment: session is set it return 1 ture but how to get all data through             print_r($this->session->userdata['logged']);

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

You can simple get the session data in codeigniter by writing

```
$username = $this->session->userdata('uname');//uname is the session variable name.
```

You can send data to other controller from ajax like this.

```
<input hidden name="uname" value="<?php echo $username ?>" id="uname">

function(){
  var uname = $("#uname").val(); 
  $.ajax({
    url: "" ,
    type : "POST", 
    data:{username:uname},

  }).done(function(data){

  }).fail(function(data){
     console.log("hello fail");

  });//end fail
}
```

You can send other fields of data also like this. Hope this will help you.

Comment: but session is set in login autho

Comment: i want fetch all the data username first name last name through session

Comment: simple change the session variable to `$data = $this->session->all_userdata();`

Answer (score 0):

**Alter this in Controller**

```
$data_session_set = array(
   'uname'  => $this->input->post('uname'),
   'logged_in' => TRUE # add this insted of 'logged' => 1
);

$this->session->set_userdata($data_session_set);
```

> I recommended you to use `logged_in` instead of `logged`

---

**Add this in your View**

```
echo $this->session->userdata('uname');
```

or try

```
print_r($this->session->userdata('uname'));
```

---

**References**

[Retrieving Session Data - codeigniter.com](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#retrieving-session-data)

Comment: did you check this??